# Display List Items SP 2010

Tags: 2010, list

I am a novice at best in working with SharePoint. I have a few issues that I would love one or all of you to help me with.

I am in the US Army,in an Airborne unit and one of my tasks is to maintain the unit Jump Logs.  As with everything in the Army there is a Standard Form for that. I have those forms in PDF, Excel, MS Word as well as Infopath.  I have created a list where we input jumps and this info is maintained on Sharepoint 2010.

So here are the steps:

1. We develop a manifest and this could be 10 soldiers or 110 soldiers.
2. Once the jump is complete I sit down and enter every soldier into
   the same list.  I can sort by last name, date, etc ... You get the
   point.

Now here is my question, is there a way to have only a soldier populate a jump log form.  So for instance, if I wanted to see MY jump log how would I sort and then export this info to my form in one of those formats listed above?  Keep in mind I have 60 + jumps and all of those need to appear in the log.  Once this is solved how can I then save this form on SP and whenever I open it will it update with the latest jumps from the list automatically?

I understand this may be confusing as I truly don't know or understand the language you guys sometimes use.  If anyone of you is willing to help I will be glad to chat or send you any of the docs you need.

Comment: You question is bit confusing.  Can you explain manifest and jump relation.

Comment: Are you asking that you would like to enter data into one of the Standard Army Forms and then push the data to Sharepoint or are you asking about entering data into the sharepoint list and pushing out to the Army Standard Forms?

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Ideally both would be amazing but for the time being push a list to a Army Fom.

Comment: Miss Monica,   There is no relationship on SP between the Manifest and Jump.  The manifest is the list of individuals jumping and the Jump log would be your individual log of all your jumps.  Does this help?  Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming that you are entering data into the sharepoint list and would like to export to pdf, excel, word, etc...

I would create new views, specifically data sheet view and choose the columns of your list to view, from there you can export to excel.

From excel you can print to pdf.

I am not sure how it would work in Word or InfoPath, formatting might be an issue.

If you are not using Office Professional, then you should install Access Database Runtime.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Comment: I will try that!  Thanks for answer..  I never thought about the view in data sheet view.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a InfoPath form and want to push information from a list to the InfoPath form.

In InfoPath under the Data ribbon create a data connection to your SharePoint List ("Get External Data" -> "From SharePoint List"). Now you have the data connected to your form and just have to come up with a way how to display it.
I can't help you with that, because I don't know how your form looks and behaves, but some hints for you:

- Maybe use a drop-down list box as a filter
- Take a look at repeating sections, it may help you to display several jumps

Comment: Awesome,I will give it a try...